# Constructor returns undefined in JS

Tags: javascript, date, constructor, this

I am trying to get the current date to show up on HTML but it is showing up as undefined. The console does return the date in the right form though and there are no errors that popped up in the console. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
// get date
var today = new Date();
var date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate()+'-'+today.getFullYear();
document.getElementsByClassName('date').innerHTML = date;
console.log(date);

// think there is something wrong with this constructor because right now the selected HTML element returns undefined 
class Note {
  constructor(title, body, date){
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.date = date;
    this.id = Math.random();
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<h3 class = "date">${note.date}</h3>
```

Comment: of course it will return undefined, you haven't created a new Note class with its contructor data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```js
class Note {
    constructor(title, body, date){
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.date = date;
        this.id = Math.random();
    }
}

const today = new Date();
const date = `${today.getMonth() + 1}-${today.getDate()}-${today.getFullYear()}`;
const note = new Note("Some Title", "Some Body", date);
document.querySelector("span").innerText = note.date;
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Or something like this:

```js
class Note {

    id = -1;

    constructor(title, body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.date = new Date().toDateString();
        this.id ++;
    }
}

const { title, body, date, id } = new Note("Some Title", "Some Body");
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = `
    <h1>${title}</h1>
    <p>${body}</p>
    <small>${date}</small>
    <br />
    <b>ID: ${id}</b>
`;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Hopefully you can get the idea here

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! The code works by itself but when I integrate it into my code, this line `document.querySelector("span").innerText = note.date;`gives the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null" in the console. Any ideas why?

Comment: @IvyChen you need to make sure that `span` tag exist. `querySelector` was just an example here. You could use `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: @IvyChen https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
let note = new Note("title" , "body" , date);

console.log(note.date , note.body , note.title)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.